# how to debug php file(s) in VSCode with namespaces and use-operator?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, namespaces, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug in VSCode php code like this:

```
use Path\ClassName;

$variable = new ClassName();
```

using the "Launch currently open script" predefined debugger setting.
But I'm getting an error like 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'ClassName' not found in blablabla...'

So seems as php just cannot process the use directory?

How can I handle with this?
(actually I don't want to use the debugging via webserver+xdebug cause my local web-server deeply connected with production system instance)

Comment: do you use somekind of bootstrap/autoloader? It seems just like it doesn't know your namespace. In that case you just might need to include the specific file. If you take a look at user notes here: [https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: no I'm using just "pure php" - 1 file with class definition and 1 that is loading this class using the use operator

Comment: well, in that case the second file is not familiar with the first. You might need to include that file firstly.

Comment: I already got it and included its code using require(), thanks for advice:)